# The Maximum value of two columns with group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that contains the followings data :

```
TRIP   TRIP_DATE    TRIP_TIME
A      2018-08-08   11:00
A      2018-08-09   11:00
A      2018-08-08   23:00
A      2018-08-20   11:00
A      2018-08-20   14:00
```

I want the select statement to retrieve the Number of trips, Count , the latest date and time. 
Basically the output should be like this:

```
TRIPS   MAX(TRIP_DATE)    TRIP_TIME
5       2018-08-20        14:00
```

Comment: mysql or oracle?

Comment: They are similar, You are welcome to try any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT TRIP, COUNT(TRIP) AS cnt, MAX(CONCAT(TRIP_DATE, ' ', TRIP_TIME)) AS maxDateTime 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY TRIP
```

To combine the `DATE` and `TIME` value you can use one of the following:

- using [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws): `CONCAT_WS(' ', TRIP_DATE, TRIP_TIME)`
- using [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat): `CONCAT(TRIP_DATE, ' ', TRIP_TIME)`

---

You can use the above query as sub-query to get the `DATE` and `TIME` as seperate values:

```
SELECT TRIP, cnt, DATE(maxDateTime), TIME_FORMAT(TIME(maxDateTime), '%H:%i') FROM (
   SELECT TRIP, COUNT(TRIP) AS cnt, MAX(CONCAT(TRIP_DATE, ' ', TRIP_TIME)) AS maxDateTime 
   FROM table_name
   GROUP BY TRIP
)t;
```

**Note:** I recommend to split the `DATE` and `TIME` values on the application side. I would also store the `DATE` and `TIME` value in one column as `DATETIME` instead of separate columns.

> **demos:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xcMdmivjJa29rDhHxkUmuJ/2

Comment: Thank You very much. Though, I would like to TRIP_DATE and TRIP_TIME without the concatenation.  Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky.  I think I would do:

```
select cnt, date, time
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by trip order by date desc, time desc) as seqnum
             count(*) over (partition by trip) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` function :

```
select t.*
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by trip order by date desc, time desc) seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this (assuming you wanted the `MAX` `Trip_Time` as well, its a little difficult to tell from your example):

```
SELECT COUNT(TRIP) AS Trips, 
MAX(TRIP_DATE) AS MAX(TRIP_DATE), 
MAX(TRIP_TIME) AS TRIP_TIME 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY TRIP
```

Answer (score 0):

You have option of using analytic function as will as group function here.
All will do the job . Looking at final output I believe max function with group by is more suitable.
There is no hard and fast rule but personally I prefer grouping when final outcome need to be suppressed.